# django admin page links broken and always redirect to the home page(/admin)

Tags: python, django, nginx, auth0, python-social-auth

We are running django with gunicorn + Nginx on amazon ecs with docker. For authentication and as SSO(single sign-on) provider, we are using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). The admin page links have been working fine for some time but they suddenly stopped working in our dev environment. All of the links in the admin page redirect back to the admin homepage i.e if you click on the User model to see the users you just get redirected back to the admin homepage. We have tried so many solutions and it has been a very bizarre bug for us. The main reason this error is so confusing is that we have the same exact code with similar configurations on our staging environment and all the admin page links work perfectly in it.

To enable authentication and SSO with Auth0 we are using a python library called [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and we think the problem could be caused maybe by a cookie or redirect-related issue coming from it. so we tried different configurations for it per the documentation and some StackOverflow answer to questions similar to this one but to no avail.
This is our current settings.py configuration:

```
# Auth0 Authentication Related Configs Keys
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = [
    "name",
    "email",
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_TRAILING_SLASH = False  # Remove trailing slash from routes
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN = config("SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN")
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY = config("SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY")
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET = config("SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET")
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SCOPE = ["openid", "profile", "email"]
LOGIN_URL = "/login/auth0"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
if DEBUG:
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ["state"]
else:
    # production configs
    SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ["state"]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user",
    "social_core.pipeline.user.get_username",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email",  # <--- enable this one
    "social_core.pipeline.user.create_user",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user",
    "myapp.auth0authorization.process_roles",  # <--- check the user role
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data",
    "social_core.pipeline.user.user_details",
)
```

The above same configuration is set for our staging environment too and it's working perfectly. we have no idea now why this is not working on our dev environment and couldn't even figure out where the issue is coming from. Any kind of help would be very much appreciated!

The other weird thing we realized is that in the broken link if you keep clicking it like for 3 or 4 times it works and then takes you to the correct page then when you click again on any link it redirects you back to the admin homepage.

We think the solution could be Nginx related too maybe with the redirect being in HTTPS. so here is our Nginx config

```
server {
listen 8088;

server_name _;


location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /static/ {
    root /code;
}

location /healthcheck {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    alias /code/healthcheck.txt;
}
```

}

here is the urls.py(its pretty standard)

```
# disable django admin page login and change to auth0
admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login, login_url="../../login/auth0")

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/logout/", myapp.views.logout),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),]
```

Here is a stack trace

```
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:46] "GET /admin/home/user/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:46] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/home/user/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:47] "GET /login/auth0?next=/admin/login/%3Fnext%3D/admin/home/user/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /complete/auth0?code=2iaLoqSfpxVoZK2h&state=LfV94SKx4gjssmDxGd9zaF8Y6sVvzBkD HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/home/user/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 36097
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 412
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:48] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 6432
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 380
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 331
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 392
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[13/Oct/2021 06:59:49] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
```

Comment: Hello, same problem for me (without the sso part): 302 loop on login... Did you solve it  @gedeon ?

Comment: same problem for me too. able to login on docker running on my local but it redirect back to home when trying with ecs url.